# How to configure clicking a launcher icon minimizes all related apps

Tags: 11.10, launcher

Lets say I have 4 terminals opened. If I click the terminal launcher icon it maximizes all terminal windows. If I click again it shows all of them in a windows lists fashion so I can click a specific window from the list to go to it. But how can I click again to minimize/hide them all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially you can't. There is (was) an open [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/733349?comments=all) about this, but the Unity developers/designers marked it as won't fix, despite over 100 people marking it as "affects me". So essentially... no.

Comment: The resolution of that bug was unfortunate, especially since there was a proposed merge by Marco Biscaro that works quite well in unity-3.X (11.04)

Comment: @doug and, he also is willing to write a patch for Unity 4.x if he is assured he won't be treated that way again, but they won't even reply.

Comment: Please go to the bug in launchpad and add your "affects me" and leave a comment.  Maybe if enough people complain, they'll fix this obvious bug:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/733349?comments=all